# jquery scroll div only if parent is taller

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I calculate the height of the parent so that the left div is only animated if there is empty space below itself. I have tried to calculate the parents height is greater then the question height + the margin-top.

This is a simplified version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rewsn/6/ as a example. Although in the real version the questions/answer are changed via AJAX so this is the reason I need to calculate the height each time.

Comment: I think this plugin does what you need http://blog.echoenduring.com/2010/11/15/freebie-contained-sticky-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Comment: What do you intend to do about the footer? Or should both `div`s scroll, once the right `div` runs out of scroll-room/height, or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then a simple condition like below should solve your problem.

```
if ((y + el.outerHeight()) < $container.height()) {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rewsn/7/)

```
var el = $('.answer');
var elpos = el.offset().top;
var $container = $('.container');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var mTop = y - elpos;

    if ((y + el.outerHeight()) < $container.height()) {
        if (y < elpos) {
            el.stop().animate({
                'margin-top': 0
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            el.stop().animate({
                'margin-top': y - elpos
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you mean - you want to stop "answers" being pushed lower than "questions"? something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/X3cbB/1/